# How to add span and inner html style to div tag in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div tag which I am using to display success and failure messages. I would like to do the changes in Jquery. I have another page having the same type of tag but in this page I am doing all the modifications in .cs page.
The styles I have added for the div tag in .cs page are as follows:

```
divControl.Visible = true;
divControl.Style.Add("display", "block");
divControl.InnerHtml = "<ul>" + message + "</ul>" + "<span style='float:right;margin-top:-20px;'><img src='../common/images/delete.png' onclick='CloseDiv(\"" + divControl.ClientID + "\");' /></span>";
```

I want to add the same styles to the div using Jquery. My div tag in jquery is "divMessage". Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

To add some class

```
$("#divMessage").addClass("myClass")
```

or set some css:

```
$("#divMessage").css("font-weight", "bold") ;
```

To add inner span in div

```
$("#divMessage span").addClass("someClass someOtherClass")
```

Comment: you beat me to it :(

Answer (score 0):

Transforming your code into jQuery:

```
//divControl.Visible = true;
$('#divMessage').show();
//divControl.Style.Add("display", "block");
$('#divMessage').css('display', 'block');
//divControl.InnerHtml = "<ul>" + message + "</ul>" + "<span style='float:right;margin-top:-20px;'><img src='../common/images/delete.png' onclick='CloseDiv(\"" + divControl.ClientID + "\");' /></span>";
var $ul = $('<ul />').html(message);
var $span = $('<span />')
  .css({
    float: 'right',
    marginTop: '-20px'
  })
  .html("<img src='../common/images/delete.png' onclick='CloseDiv(\"" + divControl.ClientID + "\");' />");
$('#divMessage')
  .append($ul)
  .append($span);
```